# socks daemon on Lua

Tags: sockets, lua, daemon

I'm newbie in Lua, but have an experience in PHP.
I have a project on PHP which is a demon that receives data from one socket and distributes data to connected clients via websocket. The project is pure PHP, without third-party libraries.
I want to replicate the project in Lua.

However, I have not found good examples of working with sockets on Lua.

How can I serve two sockets at the same time?
How do I get multiple incoming connections on the same port?

It's easy on PHP, but I don't understand at all how to do it on Lua. I would be grateful for pointers to documentation and good examples how to do it on Lua.

Comment: [lua-http](https://daurnimator.github.io/lua-http/0.1/) with [cqueues](http://25thandclement.com/~william/projects/cqueues.html)

Comment: corutines - that's the only way, am I right?